# A question about sampling theory

Tags: filtering, aliasing

Let`s say I have a signal

$m(t)=\cos(4\pi t) + \cos(6\pi t)$

so we can say the signal is containing frequencies $f_1= 2\mathrm{Hz}$ and $f_2= 3\mathrm{Hz}$. The cut-off frequency of the low pass filter is equal to $f_c= 3.5\mathrm{Hz}$, and the sampling frequency is $5\mathrm{Hz}$.

Is there an overlap (aliasing error) when receiving the original signal (After LPF)?

Comment: Aliasing can only happen when sampling, which you don't seem to be doing. There are many questions related to sampling and aliasing on this site, for instance https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13068/minimum-sampling-frequency-for-this-signal-to-avoid-aliasing

Comment: where is that low-pass filter going?  before the sampling (that's called an *"anti-aliasing filter"*) or after (which is called an *"anti-imaging filter"* or *"reconstruction filter"*?

Comment: After reconstruction filter ( at recieving side ) ... the question is : is there an aliasing effect in the output signal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two signals $x_1(t) = \cos(2\pi 2t)$ and $x_2(t) = \cos(2\pi 3t)$ which have frequencies of 2 and 3 Hz respectiveley, if you sample them uniformly with a sampling rate of 5 samples per second (or a sampling period $T$ of $\frac {1}{5}$ = 0.2 seconds) you will get the following two discrete time signals $$x_1[n] = x_1(nT) =  \cos(4\pi \frac {n}{5} )$$ and $$x_2[n] = x_2(nT) = \cos(6\pi \frac {n}{5})$$

It can be easily seen with simple trigonometry, ( by using $\cos(x) = \cos(2\pi-x)$) ,  that $x_1[n] = x_2[n]$ which is a manifestation of aliasing that occured on the 3hz signal, therefore, the 3Hz signal seems like 2Hz.

Comment: sorry my question has mistake ... let`s say i have a signal,m(t)=cos(4*pi*t) + cos(6*pi*t), so we can say the signal is containing frequencies F1= 2Hz and F2= 3Hz ... and the cutoff frequency of the low pass filter equal Fc= 3.5Hz , and the sampling frequency was taken 5Hz... Is there an overlap (aliasing error) when receiving the original signal (After LPF)?

Comment: Yes there is an overlap. Your sampling frequency should be above 6 hz.

Comment: note... sampling process in this case produces frequencies as same as that`s in massage signal !

Comment: yes due to aliasing 2 Hz and 3 hz signals fall on each other and become a single cosine term.

Comment: Draw the sample points on a plot of your waveform, and you will find your own explanation.

Comment: @AmmarM.Odeh Now I described in math.